# Splitting Korean and Number

Tags: python, regex, split, cjk

I need to separate Korean letters from two numbers.

Korean letter can either be one to three words making everything even more complicated.

Here are some of the Korean regex code range I know:

```
ㄱ ~ ㅎ: 0x3131 ~ 0x314e
ㅏ ~ ㅣ: 0x314f ~ 0x3163
가 ~ 힣: 0xac00 ~ 0xd7a3
```

Number on the front is always 4 digits and 5 digits for the other.

Here are some examples:

```
2019개회54321
2017가51584
2019가행견16997
```

What I need should look like this:

```
Var_A = "2019"
Var_B = "가"
Var_C = "23220"
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: If always first 4 and the last 5 are digits, why would you bother using regex? It is more useful when you do not know how many digits there are etc.

Comment: My bad. Im using Python3

Comment: Thanks for edit suggestions, as you can tell Im not even good at asking :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for regex here. Since you know the length of the numbers, you can just slice the string.

To get the first 4 digits:

```
yourString[:4]
```

To get the Korean part:

```
yourString[4:-5]
```

To get the last 5 digits:

```
yourString[-5:]
```

If you really want a regex, you can use this:

```
^(\d{4})([\u3131-\u3163\uac00-\ud7a3]+?)(\d{5})$
```

Remember to turn on the `re.UNICODE` option for Unicode matching. The front 4 digits, the Korean text, and the last 5 digits will be in Groups 1, 2 and 3 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use `regex` to resolve this issue (that is not the best solution here but that can be used in other situations):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

cjkText = '2019개회54321'
regex = re.compile(r'^(\d{4})([ㄱ-ㅣ가-힣]+)(\d{5})$')
m = re.search(regex,cjkText)
try:
  var_A, var_B, var_C = m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3)
  print var_A
  print var_B
  print var_C
except:
  print 'Input string incorrect'
```

**Notes:**

```
ㄱ ~ ㅎ: 0x3131 ~ 0x314e
ㅏ ~ ㅣ: 0x314f ~ 0x3163
가 ~ 힣: 0xac00 ~ 0xd7a3
```

The first two consecutive intervals can be regrouped into one big segment `ㄱ-ㅣ가-힣`.

**Output:**

```
2019
개회
54321
```

**Regex demo:**
https://regex101.com/r/P9oIXS/1/